# How to provide zoom height and width in zoom function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using the jQuery plugin [Elevateweb zoom](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom).
I've an image, where when I click on the image, I get the zoomed view of the image.

The normal image is small and the zoomed images is taking more space than the small image, but the image should zoom in the small image space.
So I have to give the height and width for the zoom image.

How can I do this?

```
$('#ex4').zoom({ on:'toggle',duration: 500});
```

The above code is zooming the image, for this I have to set height and width in px.
How can i do this?

Comment: Go here http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples scroll down to "Change the Zoom Window Size" and click on "Show the Code".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use: `zoomWindowWidth` and `zoomWindowHeight` to alter the size of the zoom window:

```
$('#ex4').zoom({
    on: 'toggle', 
    duration: 500,
    zoomWindowWidth:500,
    zoomWindowHeight:400
});
```

Change the values to px values.